# Can Ignite persistent one cache to multiple store?

Tags: ignite

I hope to use ignite to sync up records to multiple mysql db. For example, when some records goes into ***cacheA***, the records can be persistent to **db1** and **db2** both.

**Can it be possible?**

What I did is:

1. write a PersonStore class and build it as a jar and place it in libs\
2. first sample1.xml configure as

Blockquote

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://111.xxx.xxx:3306/test"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="xxxx"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="personCache"></property>
                <!-- Enable readThrough-->
                <property name="readThrough" value="true"></property>
                <property name="writeThrough" value="true"></property>
                <!-- Set cacheStoreFactory-->
                <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                    <bean class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder" factory-method="factoryOf">
                        <constructor-arg value="com.jguo.ignitepersistentstoredemo.PersonStore"></constructor-arg>
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="queryEntities">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                            <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.Long"></property>
                            <property name="valueType" value="com.jguo.ignitepersistentstoredemo.model.Person"></property>
                            <property name="fields">
                                <map>
                                    <entry key="id" value="java.lang.Long"></entry>
                                    <entry key="name" value="java.lang.String"></entry>
                                    <entry key="orgId" value="java.lang.Long"></entry>
                                    <entry key="salary" value="java.lang.Integer"></entry>
                                </map>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

3. Start one Ignite node *bin/ignite.sh config/sample1.xml*
4. Create another xml file sample2.xml and only modify the datasource part

Blockquote

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://222.xxx.xxx:3306/test"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="xxxx"></property>
</bean>
```

5. Start second Ignite node *bin/ignite.sh config/sample2.xml*
6. Start a client and put some record in cache **personCache**

But only one db got the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CacheConfiguration should be unified across all the nodes. That's why only one config is in effect.

If you need a CacheStore to operate against multiple DBs, you need to create a custom CacheStore which will have multiple data sources referring to different DBs and implement methods in an appropriate way.